# Change /product-category/category/name to /product-category/name

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

My product category urls currently look like: /product-category/category/**category-name**

Where the `category-name` is the only changing part. I would like to change /product-category/category to just /product-category, so my final url would look like: /product-category/**category-name**

Most of my google searches have yielded results relating to removing /product-category but I haven't found anyone talking about having this redundant extra /category in the url.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this right in Wordpress.  When you install woocommerce, a new setting shows up in you permalinks settings.  In your wordpress dashboard, go to Settings > Permalinks.  Then when you scroll down beneath your regular wordpress permalink settings you will see one for woocommerce.  There you can choose what you want to actually display.

Hope this helps out.

Update after comment

Ah I see, I read to fast.  I would think you would have to do a rewrite to the core wordpress function for categories.  Probably a decent amount of work in creating your own plugin to do it.  Looks like this plugin does a good job of it but I haven't used it. Let me know if it works.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/no-category-base-wpml/

Let me know if it works

Comment: This only modifies the first part of the url. If I modify it in the permalink settings it goes from /product-category/category/name to /modified-category/category/name

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link but that isn't what I'm looking for. That plugin is if you want to go from /product-category/name to just /name. I just want to remove the /category part in /product-category/category/name

Comment: No, that plugin does exactly what you asking.  If you had /product-category/category/category-name,  it would remove the category base giving you /product-category/category-name

Comment: Directly from the first paragraph from that page: this plugin will completely remove the mandatory 'Category Base' from your category permalinks ( e.g. myblog.com/category/my-category/ to myblog.com/my-category/ ).

Comment: Exactly but have you checked to see if it removes the woocommerce product-category as well?

Comment: It does yes. From my other searches it seems that the behaviour I'm experiencing is not the default. I'm sure it's something I can fix rather than patch with another plugin (hopefully!).